# Building light-following robot with one Arduino and one I2C; Motor.begin command just stops the code from working

Tags: arduino, i2c, motor-controller

This is my code for a light-following robot with an Arduino UNO and an I2C. I'm trying to get it all to work but whenever my `Motor.begin` command is in the code, nothing works. When I remove any motor commands, the Arduino reads what it's supposed to and the LED blinks. What can I do to fix the code??

````
#include "Grove_I2C_Motor_Driver.h"

// default I2C address is 0x0f
#define I2C_ADDRESS 0x0f
int analogPin = A4 ;
int val2 = 1;
int val = 0; 

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
  Motor.begin(I2C_ADDRESS);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  \
  int test;
val = ~analogRead(A5)/4;  
  Serial.println(val);     
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);  
  delay(500);   
   val2 = ~analogRead(A4)/4;  
  Serial.println(val);
  test=val-val2;
  if (test<5&&test>-5)
    val=val2;
  if (analogRead(A5) < -70) (Motor.speed(MOTOR1,100));
    if (analogRead(A5) > -70) (Motor.speed(MOTOR1,0));
  if (analogRead(A4) < -70) (Motor.speed(MOTOR2,100));
  if (analogRead(A4) > -70) (Motor.speed(MOTOR2,0));
    }
```
````

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't in the code. We don't know what hardware you have connected and how. What does Motor class even do, with which motor controller?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the same powersource for the motor and the arduino. It sounds like the motor is causing a brownout when it turns on. You should verify that the power supply for the motor is sufficiently powerful.